# Creating an Eloquent Object with relation included

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, foreign-key-relationship

I'm pretty much new to opps and laravel both
So, to insert the values into my `users` and `profiles` table which hav `OneToOne` relationship, Here is how my `store()` method looks like

```
public function store(Requests\StoreNewUser $request)
{
    // crate an objct of user model
        $user = new \App\User;
        // now request and assign validated input to array of column names in user table
        $user->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
        $user->last_name = $request->input('last_name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->password = $request->input('password');
        /* want to assign request input to profile table's columns in one go 
        */
        $user->profile()->user_id = $user->id; // foreign key in profiles table
        $user->profile()->mobile_no = $request->input('mobile'); 
        dd($user); // nothing related to profile is returned
}
```

I'm creating the new record, hence `dd()` never returns anything related to profile table.

Is this Because the `$user` object is not including relationship by default?
If yes Can i create the `$user` object which includes the associated relations in `User` Model ?

Or do i have to create two separate objects of each table and `save()` the data
 But then what is the significance of `push()` method ?

**EDIT 1**
P.S. yes, the relationships are already defined in `User` & `Profile` model

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may try something like the following. At first save the parent model like this:

```
$user = new \App\User;
$user->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
// ...

$user->save();
```

Then create and save the related model using something like this:

```
$profile = new \App\Profile(['mobile_no' => $request->input('mobile')]);
$user->profile()->save($profile);
```

Also make sure you have created the `profile` method in `User` model:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}
```

Comment: yes the method do exist already with the relationship.

So that said, I'll have to create two objects from `User` and `Profile` respectively but what exactly  `$user->profile()->save($profile);` signifies? how different from `$profile->save()`

Comment: It also attaches the `profile` with the `User` model so you don't have to provide the `user.id(foreign key)` when creating the `Profile` manually.

Comment: done. and what abt saving the data in one go, i.e.  if multiple users are being created by multiple individual requests at the same time on server, will they be executed in set? and not mingle up?

U may consider, i have a create user form and of some my staff operators are submitting this concurrently.

Comment: Yes, they'll be saved without any clash.

Comment: followup question  is white listing (`$fillable[]`) `mobile_no` and other non volatile info fields for `MassAssignment` ok ? I'love ur way cz i'm lazy :-D

Answer (score 4):

I thought i'd update this answer and make it applicable to Laravel 5 onwards. I'll use @The Alpha answer as a basis.

```
$profile = new \App\Profile(['mobile_no' => $request->input('mobile')]);
$user->profile()->associate($profile); // You can no longer call 'save' here
$user->profile()->save();
```

The reason for this is you can no longer call `save` on the `belongsTo` relation (or any other), this now returns an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`.

Answer (score 2):

The clean way to do it now would be having on your User Class file:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(App\Profile::class);
}
```

and in your User Controller, the following store method:

```
public function store(Requests\StoreNewUser $request)
{
    $user = App\User::create(
        $request->only(
            [
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email'
            ]
        )
    );

    $user->password = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::make($request->password);
    //or $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);

    $user->profile()->create(
        [
            'mobile_no' =>  $request->mobile;
        ]
    );

    dd($user);
}
```

I didn know if u were saving plain text password to you database or using a mutator on password attribute, anyhow the suggested above is a good practice I think

Answer (score 0):

*Is this Because the $user object is not including relationship by default? If yes Can i create the $user object which includes the associated relations in User Model ?*

Yes you should create the relationship, they're not included by *default*.

In your `User` model you'd want to do something like this:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile'); // or whatever your namespace is
}
```

This would also require you to have a `Profile` model created.

This would definitely answer your questions regarding inserting related models: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models

As The Alpha mentioned, and you also eluded to, I think you need to save your user model first then you can add via relationship.

Comment: That's already there, i forgot to mention, indeed both `hasOne` and `belongsTo` are defined in `User` and `Profile` model respectively